# How to get labels from a phinode and their corresponding basicblocks in LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm

Say the IR code looks like:

```
define void @_Z1mbb(i1 zeroext %r, i1 zeroext %y) nounwind {
entry:
  %r.addr = alloca i8, align 1
  %y.addr = alloca i8, align 1
  %l = alloca i8, align 1
  %frombool = zext i1 %r to i8
  store i8 %frombool, i8* %r.addr, align 1
  %frombool1 = zext i1 %y to i8
  store i8 %frombool1, i8* %y.addr, align 1
  %0 = load i8* %y.addr, align 1
  %tobool = trunc i8 %0 to i1
  br i1 %tobool, label %lor.end, label %lor.rhs

lor.rhs:                                          ; preds = %entry
  %1 = load i8* %r.addr, align 1
  %tobool2 = trunc i8 %1 to i1
  br label %lor.end

lor.end:                                          ; preds = %lor.rhs, %entry
  %2 = phi i1 [ true, %entry ], [ %tobool2, %lor.rhs ]
  %frombool3 = zext i1 %2 to i8
  store i8 %frombool3, i8* %l, align 1
  ret void
}
```

the phinode has 2 pairs `[ true, %entry ], [ %tobool2, %lor.rhs ]`. How do I extract `%entry` and `%lor.rhs` and find the corresponding basicblock of each pair? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PHI->getgetNumIncomingValues()`  : returns number of incoming values in PHINode

For your phi node:

```
 %2 = phi i1 [ true, %entry ], [ %tobool2, %lor.rhs ]
```

`PHI->getIncomingValue(0)` : gives `true`

`PHI->getIncomingBlock(0)` : gives `%entry`

There are iterators for blocks and values as well.

http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PHINode.html

Always refer to doxygen docs to see all the APIs associated with a class(Ex: PHINode).